# perform not being called for Delayed Jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_job 2.1.4 from collectiveidea, and it seems the perform method is never called even though the jobs are processed and removed from the queue. Am I missing something?

I'm using Rails 3.0.5 on Heroku

In the Controller:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue FacebookJob.new
```

In the Job class:

```
class FacebookJob
  def initialize
  end

  def perform
    fb_auths = Authentication.where(:provider => 'facebook')
    fb_auths.each do |auth|
      checkins = FbGraph::User.new('me', :access_token => URI.encode(auth.token)).checkins
      if checkins != nil 
        checkins.each do |checkin|
          [...]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

(the whole code: https://gist.github.com/966509)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: does DelayedJob know about the Authentication and FBGraph::User classes?  If not, you'll see exactly the behavior you describe: the items will be silently removed from the queue.

- See [this entry in the Delayed Job Wiki](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#wiki-jobs_are_silently_removed_from_the_database) in the Delayed Job Wiki.
- Try adding 'require authentication' and 'require fb_graph' (or whatever) in your facebook_job.rb file.